# "you," "your" or "yours" in this sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, writing-style, possessives, determiners, compound-possessives

I just received an email that had the following sentence,

> *We have plenty of magic that will pique your and your customers' interest.*

Aside from the obvious errors, do we use "you" "yours" or "your"?

EDIT
The original sentence, verbatim:

> "We have plenty of magic that will peak your & your customers interest."

Comment: "Your interest & your customers' interests", (I'm assuming you have multiple customers) may indeed be shortened to "Your & your customers' interests".. was that your question?

Comment: It might depend on how closely ***you*** and ***your customers*** are associated (or more exactly, the extent to which your interest and theirs are "the same"). With a married couple (or just *any* couple, in fact) it would certainly be okay to refer to ***John and Jane's** [wedding, house, whatever]*. Personally I don't see anything particularly odd about using *you* in OP's context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, indeed _you and your_ may be equally valid if said interests belong to both.

Comment: @FF With a situation where the noun is mass but obviously not necessarily common to both sets of people, isn't it better to use a couple of _interest_'s? Or 'that will pique your interest and that of your customers'?

Comment: @Edwin: In this context I think it would be perverse to suppose that ***your*** interest and the interest of your customers would be significantly different things. And even if I consider a context where they clearly *are* different (and hence liable to be pluralised), I have to say I don't much like *It is in **your** and your customers' **interests** to adopt the new payment system*. It sounds "fussy, precious" to me.

Comment: What are you considering "obvious errors"?

Comment: @FF A couple of _interest_'s is "We have plenty of magic that will pique your interest and your customers' interest." I'm not suggesting the plural form (note where the italics ended, as per Truss). Like you, I'm not happy with 'interests' after 'in'.

Comment: @FumbleFingers you changed the original sentence in your edit, thereby changing the nature of my question and the intention of the person who wrote the email.

Comment: @JEL see my edit to my question.  I have added the original sentence back.  Fumble "corrected" the sentence changing the nature of my question and the original writer's intentions, which I feel are important.

Comment: This issue has already been discussed in many places on this site; see the following question and the questions linked to it for a place to start: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4226/my-wife-and-is-seafood-collaboration-dinner?lq=1, http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/4226?lq=1

Comment: @sumelic it may be a duplicate but trying to wade through the maze of repostings, closed questions, and redirections to close-but-not-quite-the-same questions has not helped answer the question.

Comment: @michael_timofeev: yes, the linked questions are a mess, but a mess that needs to be cleaned up *sometime*. Putting it off will just add one more room (this question) to that maze. If you haven't found any good answers yet, I'll try to look through them myself to see if any say what I would.

Comment: @sumelic thanks.  I'm not lazy just can't judge which answers are correct and which are just the usual noise.  I looked on the Internet for info about "yours" and found that it could either be "your" or "yours" depending on customer or interest.  I don't know, which is why I'm looking for input.

Comment: OK, I found what appears to be the answer (use "your"). Unfortunately, it's only supported by the dubious authority of Wikipedia :(, but it nevertheless appears to be correct: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11849/nikkis-and-alices-x-vs-nikki-and-alices-x/11852#11852. I also made a meta post about this overall issue: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/7109/can-we-switch-to-a-better-canonical-question-about-using-pronouns-in-compound-po

Comment: @sumelic so the email writer has it right, "...your and your customers."?  He didn't have an apostrophe on customer, though.  Btw, I checked the link you gave for Giovanni and Wikipedia...thank you. It seems that Giovanni and Walker is like a "big noun" and gets an apostrophe at the end.

Comment: michael, there *has* to be an apostrophe. Since you didn't respond to @Born2Smile's initial comment I assumed the same as him (that you have more than one customer). Unless the original writer's intention was to make sure you realised that he doesn't know how to write English properly, I don't see what you're getting at.

Comment: michael_timofeev, indeed @FumbleFingers is right: There _has_ to be an apostrophe. The question is only on which side of the 's' it goes. If there are more than one customer, it should be where I put it. If the matter relates to only a single customer, it goes before the 's': "your and your customer's". The apostrophe must be in place regardless of whether you use _you_ or _your_

Comment: possible duplicate of [Possessive-S/apostrophe in a list, including the first and second person](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/209028/) Also [Use of the possessive apostrophe in a list](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/120449/), which is less concerned with possessive pronouns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not one correct answer, any of the solutions below are acceptable but the OP might be persuaded by the number of hits Google reports.

[Google News](https://www.google.it/search?q=%22you%20and%20your%20children%27s%22&oq=%22you%20and%20your%20children%27s%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.14327j0j8&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=%22your%20and%20your%20children%27s%22&tbm=nws&start=0) has *114 results* for **your and your children's**

> 1. *"Of the things he says that are wrong this is the most direct threat to your and your children's health."*
> 2. *Contact your legislative and congressional representatives and encourage them to support your and your children's right to privacy and push ...*

For **you and your children's** [Google News](https://www.google.it/search?q=%22you%20and%20your%20children%27s%22&oq=%22you%20and%20your%20children%27s%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.14327j0j8&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#tbm=nws&q=%22you%20and%20your%20children%27s%22) reports 323 hits

> 1. Grab your coat, hat and gloves, bundle up and head outside! Outdoor play is good for you and your children's health and physical development ...
> 2. How many babies born last year share you and your children's names?

Google reports 11,500 hits for **your name and your partner's name**

> 1. The account can be in your name and your partner’s name.
> 2. Simply enter the name of your team, your name, and your partner's name and you're all set!

51,600 hits for **your and your partner's**

> 1. This thinking reinforces the establishment of a great deal of inaccurate thinking regarding the quality of your and your partner's ideas and choices.
> 2. SimpleTax is designed to automatically maximize your and your partner's combined refunds.

and  [339,000 hits](https://www.google.it/search?q=you%20and%20your%20partner%27s&oq=you%20and%20your%20partner%27s&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=%22you%20and%20your%20partner%27s%22) for **you and your partner's**

> 1. Complete you and your partner's taxable income details
> 2. If **you and your partner's interests** are poles apart, you need to ask yourself whether you are willing to do the things you enjoy alone or with other friends.

Google seems to suggests that *“you and your customers' interest”* (if both parties have  the same interest in common) or *“interests”* is the preferred solution.

It avoids repeating the possessive adjective *your* twice in the same sentence, and if the noun that follows *you and your* is plural, it is unlikely a reader will interpret joint ownership of the thing in possession. Compare:

- You / your and your partner's name = suggests that the couple might share the same name.
- You and your partner's names = suggests at least two names per person
- You and your children's names = no ambiguity
- Your name and your partner's name =  unequivocal but repetitive. Possibly the ideal solution for government documents, tax forms etc.

In conclusion, if one is looking for a perfectly grammatical sentence and one which expresses clearly its meaning, then I suggest the following solution:

> We have plenty of magic that will pique *your interest* and *your customers'* interest.

If one is looking for the most harmonious solution, without changing the word order or any of the terms being used then this is perfectly acceptable:

> We have plenty of magic that will pique *you and your customers'* interest.

Comment: Mari-Lou, thank you for answering.  I really don't know what to think anymore on this one.  When I say "you and your customers' interest." aloud it sounds right, however I can picture myself standing in front of two people and saying "your" to one person and then turning to another and saying "your interest."  I'm going to go with your answer.

Comment: ok.  Thanks for spending the time to address this.

Comment: I think the "*You and your [noun + possessive apostrophe]*" construction is a way of saying these people are indivisible, they go together. After all we do say: "You and your partner" and "You and *your friends* / *children* / *family*" Perhaps that's why e.g. "You and your customers' needs" sounds acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to say ". . . both your and your customers' interest."

Answer (score -2):

As the interest is possessed by both the reader and their customer I would suggest:

> We have plenty of magic that will pique yours and your customers'
>   interest.

Though for comprehension and asthetics I would reformat the text as

> We have plenty of magic that will pique the interest of you and your customers'.

Comment: "the interest of you" does not sound good to me at all. Also, wouldn't "yours and your customer's interest" indicate disjoint rather than joint possession, and require the use of a plural "interests"? That's what the following answer seems to be saying if I'm interpreting it right: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55722/your-and-my-something-vs-yours-and-my

Comment: I don't think you need an apostrophe after _customers_ in your second suggested wording, since the phrase  "the interest of you and your customers" is structured so as to imply "the interest of you and the interest of your customers"—and "the interest of your customers" doesn't take an apostrophe.